# c# - how to show result of a query within the same web page in MVC

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, dropdown

I have an MVC app in which after I chose the value from dropdown menu the function is executed in which sql is handled. The dropdown is at:

```
http://localhost:9030/Courses/Index
```

And after I make a selection the result is at:

```
http://localhost:9030/Courses/getCoursesByTeachers?Teacher=(here is an ID of the element)
```

getCoursesByTeachers is the function in my controller which takes the ID as the parameter.

Here is the function:

```
public string getCoursesByTeachers(int Teacher)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Course WHERE teacher_Id = @Teacher";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=TSSKKEWKS0619;Initial Catalog=T-Timetable;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
            //string course = "No courses are being taught by this teacher";
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Teacher", Teacher);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            if (list.Count==0)
            {
                list.Add("There are no courses being taught by this teacher.");
            }

            return string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, list);
        }
```

And here is how I call it in my cshtml:

```
<h2>Courses taught by:</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("getCoursesByTeachers", "Courses", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("Teacher", (SelectList)ViewBag.Teacher, "Select teacher", new { onchange = @"form.submit()" }); // form.action('getCoursesByTeacher')
    }
```

Is there a way of modifiying it so the result is not shown at the redirected page but within the same one in the url at: http://localhost:9030/Courses/Index. (maybe like underneath it or so, I am guessing I have to change it somehow in the cshtml right? I cant figure out how and I don't want to screw it up when it works :D so I figured I ask you guys)

Hope the question was clear enough. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use either `HttpPost` attribute using same `Index` action method and call `getCoursesByTeachers` method from there returning same view, or using partial view which receives AJAX call and render query results on same page (note that `getCoursesByTeachers` in this way must converted to `ActionResult` which returning results partial view).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to retrieve the result, then insert it into the current DOM. You can drop the `<form>` tag if it has only been used to send the dropdown data.
I am using jQuery in the following example.

```
<div id="teacherResultDisplay">@*result will be inserted here*@</div>

// load on dropdown change
$('#Teacher').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val(); // assume the <option value="..."/> is the teacher id

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false, /* to prevent problems with dynamic data that gets cached */
        url: '@Url.Action("getCoursesByTeachers", "Courses")',
        data: {
            Teacher: selected
        },
        success: function (stringResult) {
            $('#teacherResultDisplay').html(stringResult);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your function need to be called getCoursesByTeachers and not index?

If you cannot change where your form action. You could rename getCoursesByTeachers to index and have the following

```
public string getCoursesByTeachers(int Teacher)
{
     return RedirectToAction("index", new { Teacher= Teacher });
}
```